# Reactjs - Translate string with components enclosed

Tags: reactjs, language-translation, react-redux-i18n

I need to translate "**Access denied. Please log in**" with "**log in**" enclosed by  Link component.

I am using a react-redux-i18n helper.

```
import {I18n} from 'react-redux-i18n';

render() {
    return (<Jumbotron>{I18n.t('accessDeny')}</Jumbotron>);
}
```

I have tried

```
export default {
  accessDeny: "Access denied. Please <Link to='/'>log in</Link>",
}
```

but it is returned as plain string:

```
Access denied. Please <Link to='/'>log in</Link>
```

Instead of "log in" in hyperlink:

```
Access denied. Please <a href='/'>log in</a>
```

Can you please give me some suggestions?

Comment: have you tried rendering the `<a>` tag directly ?

Comment: have you tried using a plain html component?
If you really need to use the react router's Link component, then you should render the Link outside of i18n. Instead do `<Link>{I18n.t('log in')}</Link>`

Comment: try using curly braces 
Access denied. Please { <Link to='/'>log in</Link>}

Comment: @Dane: I don't want a refresh so I use Link instead

Comment: @JeanAlesi: I want to keep translation maintainable so I am trying not to separate "log in" to other translation

Comment: @MukulSharma:  it doesn't work

Comment: @etihadsep What you are doing is not best practice. There should be a separation of concerns between the rendering of UI components and the programmatic logic/functionality. 
When doing internationalization, the translation layer should do just one thing, and do it well... "translate". In your example, you are doing two things, 1) translating, 2) Making opinionated decisions about the view layer in the wrong place.